# wound which is/from which she's bleeding heavily

Tags: grammar, sentence-choice

She clutches her wound which is bleeding heavily.

She clutches her wound from which she's bleeding heavily.

Can I say both? Which one is better? Is there a better way to say this?

Answer (score 1):

I think both should have a comma after "wound". Other than that, they both say the same thing, and I would prefer the version with less words.

Answer (score -1):

I think the first sentence(She clutches her wound which is bleeding heavily.)is better 'cause it's odd to say the other one.